# Variable BLDC load

Tags: motor, load, torque

I need to test several BLDC motors and their ESCs, primarily to determine the motor's capability and power consumption, as well as the ESC's ability to drive the motor at higher current. Aside from putting a prop on the motor, or connecting up a second motor with a resistor bank to use as a load, is there any common, off the shelf dynamic loads out there for smaller BLDC motors, rated to 6 lb-ft of torque? I'm not having much luck finding any, and that perhaps may be due to not having the proper terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Look at dynos for small motors. There is a variety available and they will control the load on your motor and measure the characteristic it is applying to it. These are generally a motor/generator that has the necessary instrumentation to report results and control the load it puts on the DUT (Device Under Test). It sounds like you almost have one with your resistor banks etc. I suggest using a programmable electronic load to replace the resistors and you will have the control needed. You can also monitor the output of the esc with appropriate test equipment. It would be easy to monitor temperature etc and with the proper equipment it could be automated. You might also want to look up ATE (Automated Test Equipment). This is intended as a starting point, not a final answer.

There are many DIY dynos you can build in your price range. I found several doing a quick search. I do not know what you have available in resources etc so I cannot make a recommendation.

Comment: I'm not looking for anything that complicated or expensive. Those systems cost upward of $40k, I'm looking for something in the $600-$1k. I've seen them before, they look similar to a small rotor brake, but I'm having a hard time finding one.